# Meteor build is importing server side code to client

Tags: meteor, import, build

My Meteor project has a server-side secret in the `/imports` directory that should not ever go to the client.

When viewing the source on a client, I noticed the file is in fact imported.

I searched my project directory and the only import this could have happened on contained this code in a file that is shared client / server:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    import secret from '../imports/config/secret';
    // ...
}
```

I am guessing the build tool saw the import and merged it regardless.

Is there a way around this? I need to use the secret in this file, however only if Meteor is running server-side!

---

*Note*: Please don't answer telling me that all server-side keys, etc. should not publish with the build. It's not quite the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the isServer constructs protects code from being run on the client, but it does not prevent those bytes from being served. you indicated the file itself is shared between client and server, and that's your issue.

you need to move that code to a file which is served only to the server. i.e. in a folder called "server", or a subfolder of that.

from https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories :

> Any directory named server/ is not loaded on the client. Similar to
>   wrapping your code in if (Meteor.isServer) { ... }, except the client
>   never even receives the code. Any sensitive code that you don’t want
>   served to the client, such as code containing passwords or
>   authentication mechanisms, should be kept in the server/ directory.

Comment: Okay. Now suppose I still have to require that file (now placed in server) from this other file that is served client and server, would it solve anything?

Comment: @dthree, that won't work. you'll have to do some work splitting up what's in those files, or maybe even making a call to the server to get what you need. hard to say without seeing the actual code.

Comment: Okay, i get it and that makes sense. Thanks for your help!